# Template method specialization for const char*

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

Consider this snippet:

```
struct S {
    template <typename T>
    void insert(const T& x);
};

template <>
void S::insert<char*>(const char*& x) {}

int main() {
    S s;
    s.insert("");
    return 0;
}
```

gcc fails to compile it with the following error message:

```
error: template-id 'insert<char*>' for 'void S::insert(const char*&)' does not match any template declaration
```

What's the reason for this error, and is there a way to write the specialization such that it will work?

I'm not looking for an alternative solution, I'm simply trying to understand the logic behind the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specify wrong parameter type.

Note that for `const T&`, `const` is qualified on `T` itself. Then for `T` = `char*`, `const T&` should be `char* const &` (i.e. reference to `const` pointer), not `const char* &` (i.e. reference to pointer to `const`).

BTW [Clang](http://rextester.com/PEI56062) gives more clear error message:

> candidate template ignored: could not match 'void (char *const &)' against 'void (const char *&)'

---

BTW again, for `s.insert("");` the specification won't be invoked because `""` is a `const char[1]` indeed, then the type for `T` will be deduced as `char [1]`, which doesn't match `char *`. If you want the specification works with `char[1]`, then it should be

```
template <>
void S::insert<char[1]>(char const (&) [1]) {}
```

then

```
S s;
s.insert("");
```

But it only works with `char[1]`, i.e. the `char` array with only one element. I think make it work with `const char*` would make more sense, then it should be

```
template <>
void S::insert<const char*>(const char * const &) {}
```

then

```
S s;
const char* str = "";
s.insert(str);
```

Comment: I had actually tried that, but gcc still fails to compile/link it: `undefined reference to 'void S::insert<char [1]>(char const (&) [1])'`

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune Answer revised.

Comment: Would it be possible to declare a decaying specialization that forwards to the `const char*` one, e.g. kicking in for the `s.insert("")` (literal) case?

Comment: @dfri No, the primary template is declared as reference, then `T` will always be deduced as an array; if it's declared as `template <typename T> void insert(T x);`, then `template <> void S::insert<const char*>(const char*)` will work for `insert("")`.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks. Out of curiosity (and without removing the reference in the primary template): this holds even attempting partial specialization template "hacks" and explicit use of `std::decay` (/`std::enable_if`)? (I've naturally attempted this myself but without success).

Comment: @dfri I'm not sure, but I think `std::decay` or `std::enable_if` help for implementation of SFINAE, not here, IMO.

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks for your time and feedback!